# Stacked BarChart with Callout

Tags: labeling, charts

[BarChart examples](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarChart.html?q=BarChart) include this code :

```
BarChart[Table[Callout[RandomReal[{0, 1}], Unique["text"]], 2, 8], 
   BarSpacing -> 2, ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]
```

Its result should be :

[image]

But I can't reproduce it on Win7-64 MMA v11.2.

I got this :

[image]

All callout are placed above the compressed chart.

When I try with some additional options :

```
BarChart[Table[Callout[RandomReal[{0, 1}], Unique["text"],  
   After,Appearance -> "Leader", LeaderSize -> {15, Automatic, 2}], 2, 8],
   BarSpacing -> 2, ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]
```

MMA returns

[image]

Some callouts still remain overlapped with straight leaders.

How do I reproduce the example chart ?